# How to select specific columns from a file with a string separator

Tags: text-processing, awk, files, search

I have a file with columns separated by  a string. For example:

```
one<xx>two<xx>three<xx>four<xx>five<xx>six
one11<xx>two11<xx>three11<xx>four11<xx>five11<xx>six11
```

I want to extract the text of specific columns, for example, column 1, 3, and 5. So the output should be:

```
one<xx>three<xx>five
one11<xx>three11<xx>five11
```

How to do this? using commands like `awk` for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set input field separator (`FS`) and output field separator (`OFS`) to `<xx>`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="<xx>"} {print $1,$2,$5}' file
```

Output:

```
one<xx>two<xx>five
one11<xx>two11<xx>five11
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ perl -F'<xxx>' -pale ' $"="<xxx>";$_ = "@F[1,3,5]"' file
```

Set the field separator to the desired string, then collect the indices of the fields, join them with string in $" and store as current record. -p will autoprint.